# Does Foundry allow for a vector DB backing to datasets? For calculating nearest neighbor and such?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Need to query a DB of user embeddings for similarity search....would it have to be external? and if so, would the only way in be the rest-api data connection?

Nothing tried. This is literally a question about Foundry. Asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve that, but the most straightforward way is to ingest the data you want to run similarity search and follow the main documentation there: [Create an end-to-end Similarity Search Workflow](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/create-an-end-to-end-semantic-search-workflow/index.html)

The global idea will be: ingest the data, create embeddings/vectors, create an Ontology/add the embeddings/vectors to an existing Object, use Foundry Function to query to perform the similarity search on the fly.

If you wish to expose this capability outside Foundry (e.g. to use via API) you can use [@query decorator](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/query-functions/) on your Foundry Functions.

Comment: There is no public API to call functions.

Comment: There is and the above documentation link is the answer. You need `@Query` to be added as a decorator to the Foundry Function you want to query from outside Foundry.
The related api-gateway's API to query a `@Query` Function is: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/ontology-resources/queries/execute-query/

Comment: Yeah i see that you can have a vector property for the objects, but what is the backing store there? Is it still the file system

Comment: You create the vectors (array of floats) as a column of your backing dataset, indeed (if that's what you mean). Once indexed in the Ontology you will have performant searches on it.

Comment: That API docs must have been recently added. Thanks for pointing me to it.